# View that filters content based on current page

Tags: views

I'm in the middle of a Drupal 6 to 8 migration and am attempting to recreate a view.  This view would appear on pages of the content type "People" and would show the "Publications" that this person is associated with.  The "Publications" has a field of type "Entity reference" that references each of the "People" titles.

How do I configure the view block to only show Publications that have the entity reference of the current "People" page?  I figure this has something to deal with contextual filters, but I'm a bit lost on how to filter this correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating Drupal 6 Views in Drupal 8 should be quite straightforward. What got you confused?

You need to create a list of all "Child" nodes (Publications) and add the Contextual filter for the Entity reference field that references the "parent". Configure that filter to use the "**Provide default value**", "**Content ID from URL**". Adjust all the other options in the filter to your specific needs.

When you add the Block to a region in your theme you also have to set the option again (in the Block settings) for the Contextual filter to use the Content ID from URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was what I needed.